# Adding Carriage Return on STUFF()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using TSQL `STUFF()` syntax (see below) to concatenate Client field into one single row, and the code works like a charm, but now I have another challenge, I need to add a carriage return for each client to show the client per line instead of continuously.

```
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Client 
FROM #Resulttbl
WHERE [row_date] = r.[row_Date]
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + CHAR(13)ELSE Client END)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Added `+char(13)` to your query and increased stuff from 2 to 3.

```
STUFF((SELECT ', '+ CHAR(13) + Client 
FROM #Resulttbl
WHERE [row_date] = r.[row_Date]
FOR XML PATH('')
, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 3, '') + CHAR(13)ELSE Client END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your entire stuff function with a replace. I kind of had to guess what your code is because you seem to have a portion of a case expression left in here.

```
REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Client 
FROM #Resulttbl
WHERE [row_date] = r.[row_Date]
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''), ', ', ',' + char(13))
```